# Trying for a special Active Record Model which works as a unique WORM registry

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I am trying to create a Model of a pretty special kind.

I just call it Emails. Containing fields like:
  address
  send_count
  blocked

It is a registry of email addresses. Every record in other models that contain an email address should have a reference to a record in this model. That way I can block/ban and email address globally in my app and flag it in other ways.

If it was not generally frowned upon, I'd say the address should work much like the primary key. I can only be set on create and then never updated and it must be unique.

My problems implementing this (with a normal primary key) is how to handle cased where Emails is updated/created as an associated model via nested attributes. This is the most common situation since the email addressed look just like any other field to the users of the application.

They might be editing their account form and happen to change their email address. Phone should notice this and "find_or_create" an instance of itself instead of updating the address. Updating the blocked property on the other hand should be allowed.

Am I getting the gist of it across? Can anyone give me some advice on how to make the Model behave like this?

I have tried some variations of using validations and callbacks but I can seem to "replace self" with another existing record. Just setting all attributes (incl. id) to those of the existing record does not really make things work fully.

Any ideas would be helpful.